# Асинхронная работа с вебсокетами

Tags: python, websocket, asyncio

### Как я могу реализовать асинхронную отправку ответов на пинг запросы чтобы они не зависели от отправки основных запросов?

Из документации по работе с этим вебсокетом:

[image]

В приведенном ниже коде я пытался сделать ввод из консоли, чтобы как только я введу в консоль "LG" он отправит запрос на аутентификацию, но сервер не дает этого сделать. Т.к. `input` блокирующий оператор, я пропускаю пинг запросы и соответственно не могу на них ответить. Как я могу на них отвечать параллельно независимо от моих собственных запросов к серверу?

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import json


async def main():
    url = 'wss://***'
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        while True:
            command_counter += 1
            recv = await ws.recv()
            response = json.loads(recv)
            print(f'{command_counter} RECV: {response}')

            if response['Type'] == 1:
                msg = response['Msg']
                data = {
                    "Type": 2,
                    "Msg": msg
                }
                print(f"{command_counter} SEND: {data}")
                await ws.send(json.dumps(data))

            command = input('>>> ')

            if command == 'LG':
                data = {
                    "RequestId": 2,
                    "OriginalRequestId": 2,
                    "RequestType": "LoginRequest",
                    "Message": {
                        "UserName": "***",
                        "Password": "***"
                    }
                }
                print(f"{command_counter} SEND: {data}")
                await ws.send(json.dumps(data))


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454190/python-async-waiting-for-stdin-input-while-doing-other-stuff

Comment: просто не блокируй инпут и будет тебе счастье

Comment: @eri да вроде бы специально не блокирую

Comment: @RoyalGoose тут же написал input - вот и заблокировался

Comment: @eri а как мне еще из консоли команду получить?

Comment: [aioconsole](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole) предоставляет функцию `ainput` — асинхронный аналог input'а

Comment: @RoyalGoose или в потоке отдельном +asyncio.Queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для асинхронного ввода используется библиотека [aioconsole](https://pypi.org/project/aioconsole/)

Пример:
`line = await aioconsole.ainput('Ввод >>>')`