# Асинхронная работа websocket клиента и flask приложения

Tags: python, flask, websocket, asyncio

Вопрос вытек из предыдущего [Асинхронная работа с вебсокетами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1287107/%d0%90%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Я бы хотел написать `flask` веб-приложение, к которому я бы мог отправлять из вне API запросы типа

```
{ 'key': 'value', 'message': 'data' }
```

И которое внутри себя отправляло их на другой вебсокет сервер

Проблема возникла в асинхронности, поскольку если я просто сделаю

```
from flask import Flask, request
import websockets
import asyncio

app = Flask(__name__)

async def wssend(data):
    url = "ws://localhost:3333"
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(data)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    req = request.args.to_dict()
    if 'key' == req['key']: # типа проверка api ключа
        data = 'data' # какие то данные
        wssend(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

То, пока от меня запросов нет, он ничего не отправит, а там нужно постоянно отправлять веб серверу пинги вне зависимости от моих сообщений. Т.е. приложение внутри себя должно постоянно держать вебсокет соединение и пересылать пинг-запросы, а как только я обращаюсь к нему, то он уже мои данные пересылает. Как возможно это реализовать и возможно ли?

p.s. у меня есть два отдельных куска кода, один это обычный вебсокет клиент, который общается с сервером (из прошлого вопроса) и flask приложение для получения api запросов. И вот хотелось бы их как-то связать в одно единое

Comment: Во-первых, созданная вами корутина `wssend(data)` не передаётся на выполнение никакому event loop'у, поэтому она ничего и не отправляет. Во-вторых, Flask в принципе не умеет работать с асинхронным кодом, так что это всё немножко бессмысленно...

Comment: Технически, Flask 2.0 позволяет использовать асинхронные вьюхи (`async def main()`) и тогда `await wssend(data)` выполнится, однако фласк всё равно заблокирует текущий поток и настоящей асинхронности не будет. Если нет возможности отказаться от Flask, вероятно, будет разумнее найти какую-нибудь синхронную библиотеку для работы с вебсокетами

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за комментарий, в принципе к flask не привязан. Если подскажите как можно решить с помощью другого фреймворка буду благодарен